# How do I do the image mouse hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change my code to allow it to change image when I hover my mouse over the current image?

The image I wish to change sits in the `body` of my webpage:

```
<body>

<!-- Here's myImage!-->
<img src="myImage.jpg" alt="BM" style="width:141px;height:114px; position:absolute; top: 300px; left: 450px;">
```

and I would like this image for example, to change to a new image, `anotherImage.jpg`when you hover over `myImage.jpg`. I attempted to find help elsewhere but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript's `onmouseover` event, but it's considered best to use CSS where possible.

Here is a demo of one possible solution: [(Edit on Codepen)](http://codepen.io/Xhaerithius/pen/XdePLE)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.container:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animals" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/people" />
</div>
```

Basically, the way in which this works is that the two images are made the same size through CSS, and placed on top of each other (that's what the absolute positioning is for). When the user is not hovering over it, the second image will have an opacity of 0 (the `nth-of-type(2)` selector selects the second element of that type), so it is not visible, and the first one has an opacity of 1, so it is visible. When the user hovers over it, the second one is given an opacity of 1, so it becomes fully visible, and since they are both the same size and on top of each other, the first one is covered by the second. This means that the image changes when you hover over it.

Another advantage to this is that, as you can see in the demo, it is fully animateable! Other solutions, such as using `display: none` or background images cannot be used with CSS transitions, as they are not animateable properties, but opacity is animatable, so you can create transitions such as this! Good luck!

If you didn't understand my explanation of how this works, feel free to ask for clarification!

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I'm having a slight issue though, do you know why for some reason when I try to edit the position of the images (via padding, top, left etc.), they don't move? At the moment they're in the top left corner however I need to move them, but having slight problems doing so.

Comment: You need to move the entire div.content for it to move, as moving the individual images with stop this from working XP. Does that work for you? **EDIT: I've edited the demo above to show you how to move it!**

Comment: This work perfectly, thank you! Just a quick question, is it possible to move the image that fades **in**? i.e the image **behind** the one you see before you mouse hover.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; What do you mean? If you use the `nth-of-type(n)` selector you can select the one that you want, and you can use the `left`,`right`, `top`, and `bottom` properties on them, if that's what you mean...

Comment: No worries, I was able to fix it, forgot how exactly, but I'd like to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add both images into a `<span>` tag or so, you could do this:

```css
span img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
span:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
span:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/2">
</span>
```

Or, use a pseudo element for the second image.

```css
span:hover img {
  display: none;
}
span:hover:after {
  content: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/2");
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/1">
</span>
```

See this **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7pr5cht/)** for an example of some basic fade in/out effects.

Comment: +1 for the pseudo element example! That's a clever use of it!. Although it does mean that the image is only loaded on hover right? It could, I suppose, be restructured to make it load the image with the rest of the page? That might be better so that people on slower connections don't have to suffer from it getting in their way while it's loading. The idea of the pseudo element is ingenious though! xP

Comment: Thanks, it is only loaded on hover in the second approach. but it can be modified as needed. Just to suggest some ideas and want to keep the examples simple.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS make the first class contain the first image. Then the second class will be the class name + hover. EX. .CLASSNAME:hover {}

```
#NAME {
   background-image: url('LibraryTransparent.png');
   height: 70px;
   width: 120px;
}

#NAME:hover {
   background-image: url('LibraryHoverTrans.png');
}
```

Comment: Whilst this does technically work, it may not always be very good for semantics... Background images aren't content, they are styles, whereas actual images are part of the actual content. XP